# Select the highest value of one column per group

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I want to show the value of the `porcentaje` column, but only those records which have the highest id (per `item`):

```
SELECT tb_avance.item, tb_avance.id, tb_proceso.porcentaje
    FROM tb_avance_detalle
    INNER JOIN tb_avance on tb_avance_detalle.id_avance=tb_avance.id
    INNER JOIN tb_proceso ON tb_proceso.id_avance_detalle=tb_avance_detalle.id
    INNER JOIN tb_mapa ON tb_mapa.id = tb_avance_detalle.id_mapa
    WHERE tb_mapa.manzana=107 AND tb_mapa.lote=12
```

Output:

```
item                       id     porcentaje
--------------------------------------------
EXCAVACION DE FUNDACION    90     100
EXCAVACION DE FUNDACION    91     50
HORMIGON FUNDACIONES       92     90
HORMIGON FUNDACIONES       93     40
```

I want to show only the marked records:

```
item                       id     porcentaje
--------------------------------------------
EXCAVACION DE FUNDACION    90     100
EXCAVACION DE FUNDACION    91     50 <------
HORMIGON FUNDACIONES       92     90
HORMIGON FUNDACIONES       93     40 <------
```

like this

```
item                       id     porcentaje
--------------------------------------------
EXCAVACION DE FUNDACION    91     50
HORMIGON FUNDACIONES       93     40
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by the item, and then you could use `group_concat` which has an `order by` clause, and then extract the first value from it:

```
SELECT     tb_avance.item, 
           max(tb_avance.id) as id,
           cast(group_concat(tb_proceso.porcentaje order by id desc) as unsigned) 
              as porcentaje
FROM       tb_avance_detalle
INNER JOIN tb_avance on tb_avance_detalle.id_avance = tb_avance.id
INNER JOIN tb_proceso ON tb_proceso.id_avance_detalle = tb_avance_detalle.id
INNER JOIN tb_mapa ON tb_mapa.id = tb_avance_detalle.id_mapa
WHERE      tb_mapa.manzana = 107 
       AND tb_mapa.lote = 12
GROUP BY   tb_avance.item
```